# Tikz /.style with two parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How do I pass two parameters to a tikz style?  I would like to do something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    transformer/.style={draw, cylinder, gray!80, rotate=90, minimum height=#1, minimum width=#2},
```

And then, I want to use this style in a node:

```
\node [transformer{2.3cm}{1cm}] () at (0,0.6) {};
```

Comment: Use `style 2 args`, see page 493 of the manual (sorry, I'm currently to lazy to write and test a complete answer).

Comment: @Caramdir: Thanks for the link.  Much appreciated — absolutely no need to apologize.

Comment: I think you have to use something like `[transformer={2.3cm}{1cm}]`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}  
\begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty} 

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    transformer/.style 2 args={draw, cylinder, gray!80, rotate=90, minimum height=#1, minimum width=#2}]

\node [transformer={2.3cm}{1cm}] () at (0,0.6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, there is also `.style n args={<number of args>}{<style>}` for more arguments and `.style args={<parameter text>}{<style>}` which allows to define the arguments using a parameter text like `\def` does.

Comment: how can I achieve this with using ```\tikzstyle``` ?

Comment: You can't, I think

Comment: Where is this documented? I tried `1 args` and `1 arg` and `arg` and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JasonS one argument is implicit, use regular `t/.style={color=#1}` and `\node [t=blue] {};`

Comment: sigh... I look forward to typst's version of TikZ